# Graphic Class not working on AIR Mobile Application?

Tags: android, flash, mobile, air, sprite

I'm trying use the Graphic Class in Air mobile (building on Flahs Professional CS6), but my Sprites not working on device, but in my computer, on Flash Player, they working well.

What the problem? Does this class does not work in AIR MOBILE?

Thanks ;)

PS: I'm using a Android device.

Comment: you need to be more specific.  Do you get an error? does it just not show up?   Show some code too

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my problem is solved, was the Loader to load the image URL, on android the EventListener `Event.COMPLETE` don't work. My code takes a bitmap e fill the sprite, so on my PC this work, but on device not. I change from `Event.COMPLETE` to `Event.ACTIVATE`, and it work.

Before:

```
loader.load(requestURL);    
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, desenharImagem);
```

Now:

```
loader.load(requestURL);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, desenharImagem);
```